# Set validation message

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to set a validation message for a set_rule....is this possible?

I tried this

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('payment_amount', 'Payment Amount', 'regex_match[/^\d{0,4}(\.\d{1,2})?$/]');
$this->form_validation->set_message('payment_amount', 'This is a test');
```

and my message did not change.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you echo out the message? `<?php echo form_error('payment_amount'); ?>` (as described here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#individualerrors )

Comment: yes i did...the message appears, but does not change

Comment: Where do you set the message then?

Comment: the message is set in the controller and the form_error is set in the view.

Comment: @user1269625 Everything is set in the controller.

Comment: @user1269625 your regex will allow an empty value to be submitted. `\d{0,4}` means 0 or up to 4 digits, and `(\.\d{1,2})?` with the `?` means 0 or 1 of the preceding match group. So those two combined allow an empty value to be submitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a custom validation error message by creating a function for the rule.

This code is untested.

```
public function payment_amount($str)
{
    if (preg_match('[/^\d{0,4}(\.\d{1,2})?$/]', $str)
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('payment_amount', 'The %s field has an error');
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

Us CI's callback as follows:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('payment_amount', 'Payment Amount', 'callback_payment_amount')
```

Comment: this code does not work...now nothing displays....I had to take out the public in function because it caused an error.

Comment: Sounds to me like you didn't put this function in the controller?

Comment: not having public and having public is the same. functions defaults to public.

Answer (score 0):

Create MY_Form_validation.php & put your code into.

Use the documentation (http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html)

Extending Native Libraries

If all you need to do is add some functionality to an existing library - perhaps add a function or two - then it's overkill to replace the entire library with your version. In this case it's better to simply extend the class. Extending a class is nearly identical to replacing a class with a couple exceptions:

The class declaration must extend the parent class.
Your new class name and filename must be prefixed with MY_ (this item is configurable. See below.).
For example, to extend the native Email class you'll create a file named application/libraries/MY_Email.php, and declare your class with:

```
class MY_Email extends CI_Email {

}
```

Note: If you need to use a constructor in your class make sure you extend the parent constructor:

```
class MY_Email extends CI_Email {

  public function __construct()
  {
      parent::__construct();
  }
}
```